# NSMutableString stringWithFormat

Tags: cocoa, ascii, nsmutablestring, stringwithformat

I have java code that prepares a message for a MD5 munge

```
private static char[] jimsCopyRight = {
```

'C', 'o', 'p', 'y', 'r', 'i', 'g', 'h',
  't', ':', ' ', 0xa9, ' '};

which is used in

```
StringBuffer message = new StringBuffer();
```

message.append(name.toLowerCase());
  message.append(new String(jimsCopyRight));

When I print out the message using

```
for(int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++){
```

System.out.println(" i = " + i + " char " + message.substring(i, i + 1) + " charAT " + message.charAt(i));
  }

I get   i = 14 char \251 charAT \251 and the message.toString is jimCopyright: \251

I need to construct a NSMutableString with the same characters.

Among the things I have tried

```
wDevCopyright = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"jimCopyright: %c ", 0xa9];
for(int i = 0; i < [message length]; i++){
  NSLog(@"i = %d char %c %d", i, [message characterAtIndex:i], [message characterAtIndex:i]);
 }
```

Which gives me  i = 14 char © 169

Any help in getting the NSMutableString to be the same as the StringBuffer will be appreciated.

---

The problem is that when I munge the two strings in MD5 I get different results when I add the 0xa9.  The prints are just for getting a look at the strings.

I'm thinking it has something to do with the char[] in Java and the construct of the NSMutableString.  I do not believe they are the same values.

I have some C code and it declares the copyright as

```
#define jimsCopyRight  "Copyright: � "
```

The Java MD5 and C MD5 of the copyright are the same.

Comment: 0xa9 is 169, and unicode char 169 is the (c) symbol, so the question really is, why does the java case think its char 251?

Comment: It would appear that in your java case, your output stream is not unicode, and you're looking at the output stream itself, and you're seeing some different encoding result, if you change you loop to

Comment: ystem.out.println(" i = " + i + " char " + message.substring(i, i + 1) + " charAT " + Integer.valueOf(message.charAt(i))); you'll see that the char is still codepoint 169 ( i = 11 char © charAT 169)

Comment: @superfell: \251 is an octal escape sequence. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The copyright symbol is what you wanted, right? According to your question, that's what you got. So what's the problem?

(This is why magic numbers are bad. I can't tell from your code alone what encoding's `0xa9` you wanted.)

If you're wondering why it says 169 instead of 251, it's because Java prints out the octal (base-8) character escape sequence, whereas `%d` in the C standard library, Core Foundation, and Foundation prints out the value as *decimal* (base-10). `\251` is not the two hundred and fifty-first character. Use `%o` to print the value as octal, or %x to print it as hexadecimal (base-16). Or, use Calculator.app's Programming mode to convert 251 from octal to decimal.

BTW, you can use the `%@` format sequence and the `NSUserName` function to insert your username into the string, just like you did in the Java code. No need to hard-code it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am debugging a MD5 hash problem and I thought it was the strings, but it is actually a CC_MD5 UTF8String issue.

Answer (score 0):

You’re missing an “s” in “jim[s]Copyright” in the Objective-C version.